# Cannot run TensorFlow compiled with MKL

Tags: c++, tensorflow, compilation, intel, intel-mkl

I've compiled the latest TensorFlow on Ubuntu 16.04 with CUDA and MKL like so

```
bazel build --config=opt --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" --config=mkl --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

And now when I'm trying to run it I'm getting an error saying that one of intel's libraries can't be found. I've also found other people who're installing a different DNN framework struggling with this https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/Paddle/issues/3213 and found an Intel doc https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-dnn-part-1-library-overview-and-installation that basically says that these files should become avilable when you follow the directions in that doc as far as I understood this. I've followed those directions and everything seems to have worked, but in reality those `libmklml_intel.so` and `libiomp5.so` files weren't added to `/usr/local/lib`.

```
>>> import tensorflow

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libmklml_intel.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Edit:
actually, they were located in `/mkl-dnn/external/mklml_lnx_2018.0.20170720/lib` after I've cloned `mkl-dnn` git and followed directions in https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-dnn-part-1-library-overview-and-installation

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the libs were located in `/mkl-dnn/external/mklml_lnx_2018.0.20170720/lib` after I've cloned mkl-dnn git and followed directions in https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-dnn-part-1-library-overview-and-installation

So I copied them into `/usr/local/lib` and included those folders in `.bashrc` as

export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

and reloaded .bashrc

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

And now TensorFlow works.